# addition calculation within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to calculate the total of all miles travelled. For example, 50 + 70 + 20 = 140.

I tried the following code but all that was returned was 'NaN':

```
var totalmiles = car1.miles + car2.miles + car3.miles
```

This is the code I'm working with:

```js
var car1 = {type:"Holden", miles:50};
var car2 = {type:"Ford", miles:70};
var car3 = {type:"BMW", miles:20};
var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];
var totalmiles = car1.miles + car2.miles + car3.miles

console.log(totalmiles);
```

Comment: The code shown in the question outputs `140`, not `NaN`. Is the real problem that you want to know how to sum up the values in `cararray` without referencing the `car1`, `car2`, and `car3` variables directly?

Comment: sorry yes the above code does work. It would not work for me at the time due to other non-functioning code which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not even using the array here. If you need to use the array in the future, try using `reduce` for a nice one-line solution. A `for..of` loop will work as well, but it takes up more lines.

```js
var car1 = {type:"Holden", miles:50};
var car2 = {type:"Ford", miles:70};
var car3 = {type:"BMW", miles:20};
var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];

function getSumReduce(arr) {
  // 0 is the starting value of "sum"
  return arr.reduce((sum, car) => sum + car.miles, 0);
}

function getSumLoop(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var car of arr) {
    sum += car.miles;
  }
  return sum;
}
  

console.log(getSumReduce(cararray));
console.log(getSumLoop(cararray));
```